# Showing a morphism is birational

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$~$ Hey y'all, I was wondering if you could help me with the following: let $f: \mathbb{A}^1\rightarrow V(x^2-y^3,y^2-z^3)$ be the map defined by $f(a)=(a^9,a^6,a^4)$. How can I show that $f$ is birational? Thank you for your help $:)$

Answer (score 1):

By providing the inverse. How about $g(x, y, z) = \frac {yz} x$? Prove that $f$ and $g$ are inverse to each other (obviously they are both rational).

Comment: Thank you for responding! Yeah, I can see why they're inverses, but don't we need $f$'s inverse to be a polynomial map?

Comment: No - you only need them to be rational maps (whence "birational").

Comment: Thank you for the help!! $:)$